# Twitter API - Is it broken or am I using it wrong?

Tags: twitter

When I ask it to display 10 tweets, I get one.  When I say 11, I get 3.  But when I say 20, I get 20.  Am I doing something wrong?

This is my code:

```
    <div id="twitter" class="widget">
    <div class="twitter-header"></div>
    <div class="twitter-content">

    <ul id="twitter_update_list">
        <li>Twitter feed loading</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="twitter-footer"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/trekradio.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=10"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're not seeing retweets in the timeline.  Sadly, with the method you're using, you can't use

```
include_rts=1
```

Change the line to

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json
    ?screen_name=trekradio
    &include_rts=1
    &callback=twitterCallback2
```

That will retreive the JSON with all the retweets in the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is now required on user_timeline (see: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) and version 1 of the API has retired since June 11, 2013 (see: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired).

So, if anyone gets stuck on @Terence answer, go look at the changes in the current API.